# Save a point cloud on as an image, considering the size and distance of each point

Tags: java, point-clouds

I want to save an entire point cloud as an image, considering the size and distance of each point.
I represent the pixels of the image as a one dimensional array the represents the pixels and their RGB values.

Right now, in order to print a point, what I do is the following:

```
int pixelIndex = ((int)yValue*this.imageWidth + (int)xValue) * 3;
rgbData[pixelIndex] = double2byte(pointCloud.getR());
rgbData[pixelIndex + 1] = double2byte(pointCloud.getG());
rgbData[pixelIndex + 2] = double2byte(pointCloud.getB());
```

I want to take into consideration the size of each point and their distance from the screen.

As an example, let's the every point has the size of 3. So each point should be rendered as a 3x3 square. But, one point is at a distance of 1 from the screen and another point as at a distance of 1.7. The farther point should be shown as a smaller point that the closer point.
Plus, the spaces between the points should also take into consideration the difference in sizes.

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence, how should the spaces between points influence the sizes of them?

Comment: If a point is at distance of 1 and another point is at distance 1.7 and the should be printed side by side, the distance between them should be different than if the second point distance was 2.7 no?

Comment: Isn't that a consequence of the current behavior? What are you using to draw the points?

Comment: You can see the code I posted. I set the RGB values for the array and use the following code:
BufferedImage image = bytes2RGB(width, rgbData);
   ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(fileName));